# Python - Convert list item into unicode if item is string

Tags: python, string, unicode

I've a list that can have mixed str and unicode strings:

```
lst = ['string1', u'string2', 'string3', u'string4']
```

I need to convert every list item in unicode if the item is a str. To convert a str to unicode I use:

```
s = s.decode('utf-8')
```

The problem is that if the string is already unicode and contains a non-ascii character, if I try to decode it I get UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character ...

so I thought something like:

```
lst = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in lst if isinstance(i, str)]
```

But this actually deletes from the list the unicode strings.

Comment: You could just add an `else` to copy over the unicode strings.

Comment: You probably should drop that business and move to Python 3.x which has built-in support for Unicode, and there is no `unicode` type as all strings are in Unicode by default.

Comment: Do you actually need to decode UTF-8, or are your `str` strings really only ASCII?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are filtering (removing non-matching elements); you need to use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) instead:

```
lst = [i.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in lst]
```

The `<true> if <condition> else <false>` expression here produces an output, always. Here that is the decoded string, or the original object unchanged if it is not a `str` object.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
lst = [i.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in lst ]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could use a ternary expression in your list comprehension to correctly convert elements, in my opinion it would be cleaner to extract the logic to a separate helper function:

```
def convert_to_unicode(s):
    """
    convert `s` to unicode. If `s` is already
    unicode, return `s` as is.
    """
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return s.decode('utf-8')
    else:
        return s
```

Then you can simply call the function on each element of your list:

```
lst = [convert_to_unicode(i) for i in lst]
```